# How to set timeout on Internet Explorer 8.0/9.0 to more than 10 minutes

Tags: internet-explorer

My web app has a button that executes a large query on the server, and returns a CSV file to the user.

The problem is that the query takes about 30 minutes to run, and IE (8 or 9) always times out well before then (i.e. stops waiting for the CSV file from the server because it is taking too long, and displays an error message).

I tried setting the KeepAliveTimeout and ReceiveTimeout registry keys to more than 10 minutes, but in that case, IE always times out at 10 minutes.

How can I set the time out to an arbitrary number?

Comment: How are things going down at the 'most horrible user experience of the century' competition? Don't run the query synchronously on the request thread - kick it off onto a worker thread, and arrange another request handler to provide the status of the query. Then the browser can poll for completion, without being blocked-up while waiting.

Comment: Is it just IE? And what server you are using?

Comment: Hi. Yes. Chrome will wait forever, but IE does not. I have not tested other browsers. This is purely a browser issue.

Comment: Haha, hey I am just following orders, but agreed, it is terrible UX IMHO. I think it's all the client can afford :)

Comment: I think it's beyond help, sorry.  The world will be a slightly worse place if/when you've figured out how to extend this timeout, so please don't try too hard.